# Q: How to generate chinese search url like s.1688.com, taobao.com... etc

Tags: php, encryption

Tks for reading
For example, my PHP project have a list of links, each link like:
"https://s.1688.com/selloffer/offer_search.htm?keywords=%C5%AE%CA%BF%CB%AF%D2%C2"
for searching keyword: `"女士睡衣"`,

Then, i deleted `"%C5%AE"` and my new result is `"士睡衣"`. It means `"女" = "%C5%AE"`

so i have a question: "How can i encrypt chinese keyword like this?"

I looking forward to your help!
thanks!

Comment: @PaulCrovella tks you, but it return: "
%E5%A5%B3%E5%A3%AB%E7%9D%A1%E8%A1%A3" :( not true

Comment: oppp! tks you, i see

Answer (score 1):

Code php encode url search 1688

```
$key = "女士钱包";
$str = mb_convert_encoding($key, "EUC-CN", "auto");
header("Location: https://s.1688.com/selloffer/offer_search.htm?keywords=$str");
```